# JavaPicture cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jpeg, jmf

I'm using JPegImagesToMovie to create a movie from a bunch of jpeg images, but I get an error in the java file. This is the file:

```
/*
* @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java    1.3 01/03/13
*
* Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
*
* Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
* modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
* provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
* the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
* which is disparaging to Sun.
*
* This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
* EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
* IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
* NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
* LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
* OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
* LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
* INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
* CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
* OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
* POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
*
* This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
* aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
* the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
* facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
* redistribute the Software for such purposes.
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
import javax.media.datasink.*;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.format.JPEGFormat;

/**
* This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into
* a QuickTime movie.
*/
public class JPegtoMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

public boolean doItPath(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector inFiles, String outputURL) {
    // Check for output file extension.
if (!outputURL.endsWith(".mov") && !outputURL.endsWith(".MOV")) {
    //System.err.println("The output file extension should end with a .mov extension");
    prUsage();
    }

    // Generate the output media locators.
MediaLocator oml;

if ((oml = createMediaLocator("file:" + outputURL)) == null) {
    //System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
    System.exit(0);
}

    boolean success = doIt(width, height, frameRate, inFiles, oml);

System.gc();
return success;
}



public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector inFiles, MediaLocator outML) {
ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate, inFiles);

Processor p;

try {
    //System.err.println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
    p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //System.err.println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
    return false;
}

p.addControllerListener(this);

// Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
// some processing options on the processor.
p.configure();
if (!waitForState(p, p.Configured)) {
    //System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
    p.close();
    p.deallocate();
    return false;
}

// Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime. 
p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

// Query for the processor for supported formats.
// Then set it on the processor.
TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
    //System.out.println(f[0].getEncoding());
if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
    //System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: " + tcs[0].getFormat());
    p.close();
    p.deallocate();
    return false;
}

tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

//System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

// We are done with programming the processor.  Let's just
// realize it.
p.realize();
if (!waitForState(p, p.Realized)) {
    //System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
    p.close();
    p.deallocate();
    return false;
}

// Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
DataSink dsink;
if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
    //System.err.println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: " + outML);
    p.close();
    p.deallocate();
    return false;
}

dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
fileDone = false;

//System.err.println("start processing...");

// OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
try {
    p.start();
    dsink.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    p.close();
    p.deallocate();
    dsink.close();
    //System.err.println("IO error during processing");
    return false;
}

// Wait for EndOfStream event.
waitForFileDone();

// Cleanup.
try {
    dsink.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
p.removeControllerListener(this);

//System.err.println("...done processing.");

p.close();

return true;
}


/**
 * Create the DataSink.
 */
DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

DataSource ds;

if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
    //System.err.println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
    return null;
}

DataSink dsink;

try {
    //System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
    dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
    dsink.open();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
    return null;
}

return dsink;
}


Object waitSync = new Object();
boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

/**
 * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state.
 * Return false if the transition failed.
 */
boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
synchronized (waitSync) {
    try {
    while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
        waitSync.wait();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
return stateTransitionOK;
}


/**
 * Controller Listener.
 */
public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent ||
    evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent ||
    evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
    synchronized (waitSync) {
    stateTransitionOK = true;
    waitSync.notifyAll();
    }
} else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
    synchronized (waitSync) {
    stateTransitionOK = false;
    waitSync.notifyAll();
    }
} else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
    evt.getSourceController().stop();
    evt.getSourceController().close();
}
}


Object waitFileSync = new Object();
boolean fileDone = false;
boolean fileSuccess = true;

/**
 * Block until file writing is done. 
 */
boolean waitForFileDone() {
synchronized (waitFileSync) {
    try {
    while (!fileDone)
        waitFileSync.wait();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
return fileSuccess;
}


/**
 * Event handler for the file writer.
 */
public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
    synchronized (waitFileSync) {
    fileDone = true;
    waitFileSync.notifyAll();
    }
} else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
    synchronized (waitFileSync) {
    fileDone = true;
    fileSuccess = false;
    waitFileSync.notifyAll();
    }
}
}


public static void main(String args[]) {

if (args.length == 0)
    prUsage();

// Parse the arguments.
int i = 0;
int width = -1, height = -1, frameRate = 1;
Vector inputFiles = new Vector();
String outputURL = null;

while (i < args.length) {

    if (args[i].equals("-w")) {
    i++;
    if (i >= args.length)
        prUsage();
    width = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
    } else if (args[i].equals("-h")) {
    i++;
    if (i >= args.length)
        prUsage();
    height = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
    } else if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
    i++;
    if (i >= args.length)
        prUsage();
    frameRate = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
    } else if (args[i].equals("-o")) {
    i++;
    if (i >= args.length)
        prUsage();
    outputURL = args[i];
    } else {
    inputFiles.addElement(args[i]);
    }
    i++;
}

if (outputURL == null || inputFiles.size() == 0)
    prUsage();

// Check for output file extension.
if (!outputURL.endsWith(".mov") && !outputURL.endsWith(".MOV")) {
    System.err.println("The output file extension should end with a .mov extension");
    prUsage();
}

if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
    System.err.println("Please specify the correct image size.");
    prUsage();
}

// Check the frame rate.
if (frameRate < 1)
    frameRate = 1;

// Generate the output media locators.
MediaLocator oml;

if ((oml = createMediaLocator(outputURL)) == null) {
    System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
    System.exit(0);
}

JPegtoMovie imageToMovie = new JPegtoMovie();
imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, frameRate, inputFiles, oml);

System.exit(0);
}

static void prUsage() {
System.err.println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie -w <width> -h <height> -f <frame rate> -o <output URL> <input JPEG file 1> <input JPEG file 2> ...");
System.exit(-1);
}

/**
 * Create a media locator from the given string.
 */
static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

MediaLocator ml;

if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
    return ml;

if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
    if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
    return ml;
} else {
    String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + url;
    if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
    return ml;
}

return null;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Inner classes.
///////////////////////////////////////////////


/**
 * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and
 * turn that into a stream of JMF buffers.
 * The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
 */
class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

ImageSourceStream streams[];

ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
    streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
    streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
}

public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
}

public MediaLocator getLocator() {
    return null;
}

/**
 * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video
 * frames without a container format.
 */
public String getContentType() {
    return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
}

public void connect() {
}

public void disconnect() {
}

public void start() {
}

public void stop() {
}

/**
 * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
 */
public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
    return streams;
}

/**
 * We could have derived the duration from the number of
 * frames and frame rate.  But for the purpose of this program,
 * it's not necessary.
 */
public Time getDuration() {
    return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
}

public Object[] getControls() {
    return new Object[0];
}

public Object getControl(String type) {
    return null;
}
}


/**
 * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
 */
class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

Vector images;
int width, height;
VideoFormat format;

int nextImage = 0;  // index of the next image to be read.
boolean ended = false;

public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.images = images;

    format = new JPEGFormat(new Dimension(width, height),
            Format.NOT_SPECIFIED,
            Format.byteArray,
            (float)frameRate,
                            75,
                            JPEGFormat.DEC_422);
}

/**
 * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
 */
public boolean willReadBlock() {
    return false;
}

/**
 * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth
 * of video data.
 */
public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

    // Check if we've finished all the frames.
    if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
    // We are done.  Set EndOfMedia.
    //System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
    buf.setEOM(true);
    buf.setOffset(0);
    buf.setLength(0);
    ended = true;
    return;
    }

        //For JES, we pass around JavaPictures
        //String imageFile = (String)images.elementAt(nextImage);

        JavaPicture image = (JavaPicture)images.elementAt(nextImage);
        image.saveImage(".movtemp.jpg");
        String imageFile = ".movtemp.jpg";
        nextImage++;

    //System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

    // Open a random access file for the next image. 
    RandomAccessFile raFile;
    raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

    byte data[] = null;

    // Check the input buffer type & size.

    if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
    data = (byte[])buf.getData();

    // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
    if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
    data = new byte[(int)raFile.length()];
    buf.setData(data);
    }

    // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
    raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int)raFile.length());

    //System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

    buf.setOffset(0);
    buf.setLength((int)raFile.length());
    buf.setFormat(format);
    buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | buf.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

    // Close the random access file.
    raFile.close();
}

/**
 * Return the format of each video frame.  That will be JPEG.
 */
public Format getFormat() {
    return format;
}

public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
    return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
}

public long getContentLength() {
    return 0;
}

public boolean endOfStream() {
    return ended;
}

public Object[] getControls() {
    return new Object[0];
}

public Object getControl(String type) {
    return null;
}
}
}
```

I get an error on

```
        //For JES, we pass around JavaPictures
        //String imageFile = (String)images.elementAt(nextImage);

        JavaPicture image = (JavaPicture)images.elementAt(nextImage);
        image.saveImage(".movtemp.jpg");
        String imageFile = ".movtemp.jpg";
        nextImage++;
```

I don't know what JavaPicture is and using google didn't help very much. It appears that JES is only for linux and I don't know how to use it with Windows, or even if that would work. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: If you don't know what JavaPicture is then why is it in your code?

Comment: This looks like the most documented option so I went with it.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE] or <a href="http://sscce.org/">SSCCE</a> that reproduces the problem. 
This will increase your chances of getting a helpful answer (and also may help you find the problem).

Answer (score -1):

A simple Google search turns up that `JpegImagesToMovie` originates at coweb.cc.gatech.edu.  Searching for `JavaPicture` turns up this Javadoc http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/mediaComp-plan/uploads/95/JavaPicture.html as well as a link to download the Java file.

I'd start there.